# Prove that the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series $exp: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $R= \infty$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Prove that the radius of convergence $R$ of $exp: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $R= \infty$.

Solution given in past exam paper mark scheme:
Let $a_n= \frac{1}{n!}$, then $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{1}{n!}}=\frac{n!}{nn!}=\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ Thus the radius of convergence is $R= \infty$.

Am I right in saying that some of the calculation is wrong there? It should be:
$\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{1}{n!}}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Can I also ask how this shows that the radius of convergence is $\infty$?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: Can I also ask how this shows that the radius of convergence is $\infty$?

Comment: The title should say "...of the power series for..."

Comment: The ratio of successive terms of the power series is $x/(n+1)$ and for each real $x$, that fraction goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.